# For $p\geqslant 0$ find $x$ in $x!=p$

Tags: real-analysis

So you are giving a natural number $p$ and you are told to:

> Find $x$ in $x!=p?$

What would you do?

Me: I take the $\log$ and I get: $\sum_{i=1}^{x}\log i=\log p$. and I get stuck there.
You:?

Thanks.

Comment: You could get an approximation for $x$ by computing: $$\int_1^x \log(\tau) d\tau = x\log(x)-x +1= \log(p)$$ Which may or may not be easier.

Comment: Divide by $2,3,4,...$